# Java object i use in scala are getting created several times

Tags: java, scala, playframework

i work with the Play Framework 2.5 and i use several JAVA classes trough scala in my templates. I create the object one times with

```
@import MyClass;
@foo = @{new MyClass(bar)}
```

With only that code, the contructor of MyClass is not called (i have put a debug output in the constructor too check a call of it)

Now i use a function of that JAVA class like

```
@foo.getMeSomeBar()
```

somewhere in the template. Now, the constructor is called. The Problem: every time i use a function of that class in the same template, the constructor is called.

The same problem occurs, if i pass that scala variable to another template like

```
@otherTemplate(foo)
```

Every time foo is used in otherTemplate the constructor is called.

Is this the desired behavior? If yes, why? If no, how can i avoid it?

EDIT: if i create the MyClass object in the Controller and pass it from there to the templates the constructor is only called one times. But in some cases if have to create the MyClass in the template or i have to change a lot of classes.

Comment: You should probably instantiate your `foo` in the controller, rather than the view.

Comment: I could do that. But i want to understand whats going on with my current way. If thats the desired behavior, i will switch to that.

Comment: I have no idea how Play templates internally work, but the notation `@foo` hides whether it implements a `def` or a `val`. With referential transparency, it does not matter, but with impure functions (such as a java constructor), it makes all the difference. Have you tried doing the same with an impure scala function ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have nealry no experience with scala, so i do not know excatly how i use a impure scala function in that case.

Comment: What's the exact signature of `otherTemplate`? Also, the notation you're using to instantiate the `MyClass` looks a bit odd to me.

Comment: The signature of otherTemplate is @(foo: MyClass)
The way i instantiate the MyClass is the only way without Compilation errors i found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplates#declaring-reusable-values), you should not use the `@foo = @{ ... }` to define a reusable value. The preferred way is to do

```
@defining(new MyClass(bar)) { foo =>

  @foo.getMeSomeBar()

  ...

  @otherTemplate(foo)

}
```

Your way may have unexpected results, such as re-running the code in your block every time it is called.

Comment: Thanks! That only triggers the constructor only once. As i have more than only MyClass this way gets very nested =)

Comment: As I said, you should probably create your instances in your controller anyway.